# How do I make a pause in-between commands in p5js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Title. I want to add to a variable every "x" seconds. Basically, this is what I want:

```
var count;

function draw() {
  //...

  count.count();
}

function count() {
  this.count = function() {
    pause(x);
    count++;
  }
}
```

I've looked in the reference but I can't find anything that would help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

[set_time_out](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
// simple example
var seconds = 3;

setTimeout(function() {
  // your code to be executed after 3 second
  // Since it is in milliseconds units, multiply it by 1000.
}, seconds*1000);
```

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) 
[async_function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) 
[async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

```
// using Promise & async/await
let value = 0;
let seconds = 3;

const pause = (t) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(value++);
        }, t*1000);
    });
}

const count = async () => {
    await pause(seconds);
}

const main = async () => {
    console.log(value);
    await count();
    console.log(value);
}

main();
```